# pip install turtle происходит ошибка при установке

Tags: python, pip

когда пишу pip install turtle в cmd или shell и т.д то пишет это:

> Collecting turtle   Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error   error:
> subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.   │ exit code:
> 1   ╰─> [7 lines of output]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 36, in 
> File "", line 34, in 
> File "C:\Users\U\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wq2f4m62\turtle_cd2a69021bc5434fb3a379cbcdb6cb87\setup.py",
> line 40
> except ValueError, ve:
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above
> for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

(pip install pyautogui установился нормально)

Answer (score 4):

Все потому что библиотека **turtle** - уже включена в стандартную библиотеку python, вам нужно просто прописать `import turtle`, или `from turtle import *`, и начинать работать

Comment: Нет, в консоли откладки пишет это: c:/Users/U/.vscode/extensions/actboy168.lua-debug-1.53.1/runtime/win32-x64/lua54/lua.exe: c:\Users\U\scripts\turtle text.py:1: syntax error near 'turtle'

Comment: я пробовал в Visual Studio code у меня не получилось, я попробовал в Python 3.7 и всё работает

Comment: Значит у вас проблемы с visual studio. Я бы предложил использовать библеотеку pygame для игр, если вы хотите сделать игру.